# Import HTML anchors into MS Word

Tags: microsoft-word, html, import, hyperlink, links

I have a HTML document with lots of internal links. Something like this:

```
<h1 id="anchor">A Heading</h1>
A
LOT
OF
TEXT
<a href="#anchor">Click to return to the beginning</a>.
```

The problem is that the id is not being recognised, so when you CTRL+Click on the link in Word, you're returned to the beginning of the document.

Why is my id not begin recognised, and how do I fix it? (I've already tried changing it to 'name', and that didn't work.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works in LibreOffice. (Portable version that doesn't require installation is also available.)

So, Your code works just fine in MS Word, if You'll do the following:

1. open LibreOffice Writer and create the new document (`File` > `New` > `Text Document`)
2. open your file in Internet Explorer > `ctrl + A` (select all) > `ctrl + C` (copy) > `ctrl + V` (paste to LibreOffice Writer)
3. save as "Microsoft Word 97/2000/XP/2003 (.doc)" using LibreOffice Writer
4. open with MS Word

Tested with LibreOffice Portable Version 3.6.2.2, IE 8 and MS Word 2007.

Comment: Thank you. I'd previously tried importing to LibreOffice and then exporting as .docx and .odt, without success. But .doc is working.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use an anchor element for defining the id: `<h1><a name="myanchor">...</h1`> instead of `<h1 id="myanchor">`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

While this question has been around for a while, I'd like to add a useful option. In Microsoft Office, you have the ability to insert an object of the 'Text' type. If you choose to insert HTML text, it will preserve elements such as anchors and headers. This can be a practical way to maintain the structure and functionality of your HTML content within an Office document.